# Simplest way to flatten document to a view in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

Given the following classes:

```
public class Lookup
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DocA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Lookup Currency { get; set; }
}

public class ViewA // Simply a flattened version of the doc
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; } // View just gets the name of the currency
}
```

I can create an index that allows client to query the view as follows:

```
public class A_View : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DocA, ViewA>
{
    public A_View()
    {
        Map = docs => from doc in docs
                      select new ViewA
                      {
                          Id = doc.Id,
                          Name = doc.Name,
                          CurrencyName = doc.Currency.Name
                      };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                      group on new ViewA
                      {
                          Id = result.Id,
                          Name = result.Name,
                          CurrencyName = result.CurrencyName
                      } into g
                      select new ViewA
                      {
                          Id = g.Key.Id,
                          Name = g.Key.Name,
                          CurrencyName = g.Key.CurrencyName
                      };
    }
}
```

This certainly works and produces the desired result of a view with the data transformed to the structure required at the client application. However, it is unworkably verbose,  will be a maintenance nightmare and is probably fairly inefficient with all the redundant object construction.

**Is there a simpler way of creating an index with the required structure (ViewA) given a collection of documents (DocA)?**

*FURTHER INFORMATION*
The issue appears to be that in order to have the index hold the data in the transformed structure (ViewA), we have to do a Reduce. It appears that a Reduce must have both a GROUP ON and a SELECT in order to work as expected so the following are not valid:

*INVALID REDUCE CLAUSE 1:*

```
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                      group on new ViewA
                      {
                          Id = result.Id,
                          Name = result.Name,
                          CurrencyName = result.CurrencyName
                      } into g
                      select g.Key;
```

This produces: System.InvalidOperationException: Variable initializer select must have a lambda expression with an object create expression

Clearly we need to have the 'select new'.

*INVALID REDUCE CLAUSE 2:*

```
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                      select new ViewA
                      {
                          Id = result.Id,
                          Name = result.Name,
                          CurrencyName = result.CurrencyName
                      };
```

This prduces: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.IdentifierExpression' to type 'ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.InvocationExpression'.

Clearly, we also need to have the 'group on new'.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

(Note: removing the type (ViewA) from the constructor calls has no effect on the above)

**UPDATE WITH CORRECT APPROACH**

As outlined in Daniel's blog mentioned in the answer below, here is the correct way to do this for this example:

```
public class A_View : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DocA, ViewA>
{
    public A_View()
    {
        Map = docs => from doc in docs
                      select new ViewA
                      {
                          Id = doc.Id,
                          Name = doc.Name,
                          CurrencyName = doc.Currency.Name
                      };

        // Top-level properties on ViewA that match those on DocA
        // do not need to be stored in the index.
        Store(x => x.CurrencyName, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Phill. I don't know what happened to other answer that was here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution, simply flatten in the Map and configure the index to store only properties that do not exist in DocA.

```
public class A_View : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DocA, ViewA>
{
    public A_View()
    {
        Map = docs => from doc in docs
                      select new ViewA
                      {
                          Id = doc.Id,
                          Name = doc.Name,
                          CurrencyName = doc.Currency.Name
                      };

        // Top-level properties on ViewA that match those on DocA
        // do not need to be stored in the index.
        Store(x => x.CurrencyName, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note to something I was looking after for a while; If you want to use the index to query and then get the original entity you're querying for, you can do this:

`DocumentSession.Query<ViewA, A_View>().Where(x => x.CurrencyName == "EUR").As<DocA>().First();`

[Found here](http://ayende.com/blog/152833/orders-search-in-ravendb)